# split string for returning only the latter part

Tags: java, string

I have a string like this:

```
abc:def,ghi,jkl;mno:pqr,stu;vwx:yza,aaa,bbb;
```

I want to split first on ; and then on :
Finally the output should be only the latter part around : i.e. my output should be

```
def, ghi, jkl, pqr, stu, yza,aaa,bbb
```

This can be done using Split twice i.e. once with `;` and then with `:` and then pattern match to find just the right part next to the `:`. Howvever, is there a better and optimized solution to achieve this?

Comment: Please include your code, otherwise your question is off topic (as stated in the [faq]).

Comment: I suggest using a regular expression rather than split.Agree with Rohit Jain answer.

Comment: @user1703096, you usually don´t accept answers. Too bad!

Answer (score 6):

So basically you want to fetch the content between `;` and `:`, with `:` on the left and `;` on the right.

You can use this regex: -

```
"(?<=:)(.*?)(?=;)"
```

This contains a `look-behind` for `:` and a `look-ahead` for `;`. And matches the string preceded by a `colon(:)` and followed by a `semi-colon (;)`.

**Regex Explanation: -**

```
(?<=         // Look behind assertion.
    :        // Check for preceding colon (:)
)            
(            // Capture group 1
    .        // Any character except newline
    *        // repeated 0 or more times
    ?        // Reluctant matching. (Match shortest possible string)
)
(?=          // Look ahead assertion
    ;        // Check for string followed by `semi-colon (;)`
)
```

Here's the working code: -

```
   String str = "abc:def,ghi,jkl;mno:pqr,stu;vwx:yza,aaa,bbb;";

   Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=:)(.*?)(?=;)").matcher(str);

   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
   while (matcher.find()) {
       builder.append(matcher.group(1)).append(", ");
   }

   System.out.println(builder.substring(0, builder.lastIndexOf(",")));
```

**OUTPUT: -**

```
def,ghi,jkl, pqr,stu, yza,aaa,bbb
```

Comment: Is there a tool to generate that RegexExplanation section or did you type it out by hand?  A tool would be very useful for beginners.

Comment: @CoryKendall.. I typed it by hand only. But there are many online `Regex` resources. I think you can google out. You will get many. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
String[] tabS="abc:def,ghi,jkl;mno:pqr,stu;vwx:yza,aaa,bbb;".split(";");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("(.*:)(.*)");
String sep = ",";
for (String string : tabS) {
    sb.append(patt.matcher(string).replaceAll("$2 ")); // ' ' after $2 == ';' replaced
    sb.append(sep);
}
System.out.println(sb.substring(0,sb.lastIndexOf(sep)));
```

output

```
def,ghi,jkl ,pqr,stu ,yza,aaa,bbb
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't pattern match unless you have to in Java; if you can't have the ':' character in the field name (abc in your example), you can use `indexOf(":")` to figure out the "right part".